# How to fix TPM2 ACPI table does not define a memory resource

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have a Surface Pro 3. I set it up to duel boot both Windows and Ubuntu. Today I went into Ubuntu and used the updater to install some updates. Now when I try to boot into Ubuntu it gives me a boot error that reads:

```
[   1.178527] tpm_tis MSFT0101:00 [Firmeware Bug]: TPM2 ACPI table does not define a memory resource
[   1.726939] i80042: Can't read CTR while initializing i8042

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Anyone have any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar error on Surface Pro 3. I have Ubuntu and Grub installed in a USB dongle, so when I need to boot into Ubuntu, I just plug the USB in.

If I plug the USB in while the system is turned off and then I boot up the system, I get your mentioned error and I get an emergency command prompt. But I found a method which works well for me:

#### Work Around

1. Boot the system up in Windows (without the Ubuntu dongle)
2. Plug in the dongle
3. Restart the system